# Separating Cuda CU file to many other files and OPENGL compiling issue

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda

i have a huge CU file which contains my project , im trying to separate it into small CU files , but im getting many gl.h errors , i dont know what to do... it's driving me crazy..

```
1>  Compiling CUDA source file core.cu...
1>  
1>  C:\Users\igal\Desktop\prj trying to devide files\graph>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.0\include"  -G0  --keep-dir "Debug" -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile  -D_NEXUS_DEBUG -g    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /nologo /Od /Zi  /MDd " -o "Debug\core.cu.obj" "C:\Users\igal\Desktop\prj trying to devide files\graph\core.cu" 
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\GL/gl.h(1152): error : this declaration has no storage class or type specifier
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\GL/gl.h(1152): error : expected a ";"
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\GL/gl.h(1153): error : this declaration has no storage class or type specifier
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\GL/gl.h(1153): error : variable "WINGDIAPI" has already been defined
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\GL/gl.h(1153): error : expected a ";"
```

and the list goes on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on Windows, make sure that you include `windows.h` before including `gl.h`, or any other file which may indirectly include `gl.h`.

As stated on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374218%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), this is necessary for OpenGL to work.

Comment: thanks for your answer... well i decided to do it all backwards , seperated the CPP code from the CU code and not as mentioned before.
after adding the extern "c" command before each CPP function which calls to cuda kernel  , i managed to get it working...
well my next challenge is to import the kernels to CPP classes.. not quite sure how to do it with the extern "c" command